# Put parameter / character after blogger layout data tags

Tags: html, tags, themes, blogger

I have this code on my blogger theme.

```
<a expr:href='data:post.authorProfileUrl' rel='author' title='author profile'>
```

how can I put `/?rel=author` behind `data:post.authorProfileUrl`.

I have tried to put that directly like this

```
<a expr:href='data:post.authorProfileUrl/?rel=author' rel='author' title='author profile'>
```

but it didn't work.

I'm expecting something like this

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/+ZinebAitBahajji/?rel=author">
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Display post author, date, labels and comments with icons below post titles](http://helplogger.blogspot.com/2012/02/display-post-author-date-labels-and.html)**

This is not actually what you are searching for but This article may be helpful to you. You may get some Idea from the above mention step by step article.